# Continue Thread by Id or Name

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I've been working with the java version of play framework 2.2.0. My problem at this time is, I would pause a thread that will persist some data into an database. This thread is created when a user will perform an upload. 
So if one user will write and there are 2 readers on this file that will be updated, I thougt I make the thread of the update waiting until the readers finished their read operation and add the writer thread to an database with the thread id. Further actions on this data will be also persisted in  a database with their thread id and are also waiting.

Now my Question is there a way to continue an specific thread by id?
And besides is this a good idea to perform it like this?

Comment: No, it’s everything else than a good idea. You should not “pause” threads. The threads themself (read the code they execute) should acquire the appropriate lock before performing a critical action. See [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: Thank you for this advice. That helped and i thougt about such a solution with r/w locks and try it now to implement.